# How Can I Print Running Text? For Example to Print "Stack" Python Will Print S then t then a then c and then k?

Tags: python

I am using notepad++ for writing codes and then seeing output using Windows Power Shell. Now lets say I want to print this...

"Stack Overflow"

But not all at once. First of all it will print S then t then a then c then k then a space and then O ...... ?

So is there any function/method to post the text as we type in old PCs?

If the question is not complete let me know what more information I can provide you.

**Update**

@uʍop ǝpısdn Yes, you understood my requirement. And many thanks for the answer. :)

Well I didn't know that it calls Emulating text. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here you go:

```
import time, sys

for letter in "Stack Overflow":
    sys.stdout.write(letter)
    sys.stdout.flush()
    time.sleep(1) # that's in seconds, adjust at will

sys.stdout.write('\n')
```

**Why stdout.flush?**

Output from a running program is usually buffered (i.e. held waiting) until certain conditions are met. The call to `sleep()` will not fulfill these conditions, and the text will not appear. By calling `flush()` after each letter, you force it out.

Comment: This will produce ```S t a c k   O v e r f l o w``` (with a space in between each letter)

Comment: right you are, switched to `stdout.write()`

Comment: Needs sys.stdout.flush() after each letter to make it appear.

Answer (score 1):

```
from __future__ import print_function  # only needed for Python 2.x
import random
from time import sleep

def delay_print(s, min_delay=0.1, max_delay=0.8):
    for ch in s:
        delay = min_delay + random.random() * (max_delay - min_delay)
        sleep(delay)
        print(ch, end="")
    print('')

delay_print("StackOverflow")
```